# Wkhtmltopdf : How to add page number in table tfoot

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

By now, I can add page number to my page footer. But I need to add the page number into tfoot of my table rather than to my page footer. Is it possible to do this in wkhtmltopdf?

[Here's the page number position I want to be looked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqb4y.png)

Comment: I don't think it's possible - According to the docs, page number info is only available in the header and footers, not body content.